# Auto-indent not working on Python's "with"

Tags: python, vim, indentation, auto-indent

I am using VIM 7.4 on Ubuntu 16.04, and am coding for Python 3.5.

When writing a Python file (.py), the indentation works perfectly, except for the `with` statement. Namely, I could remap <kbd>tab</kbd> to indent by four spaces, VIM automatically indents by four spaces after a colon (`:`), and so on.

But when it comes to the `with ... as` syntax, it fails indenting a newline.

Visual example:

```
if x == 12:
```

then <kbd>tab</kbd> results on an indented newline, but

```
with open("test.txt", 'r') as file:
```

then <kbd>tab</kbd> resultes on a not indented newline.

I checked a lot of questions, that I won't link because they are too numerous, but here are some of the things I tried:

- Adding `set autoindent` in my `.vimrc`;
- Adding `set smartindent` in my `.vimrc`;
- Typing `filetype indent on` in VIM's interpreter;
- Typing `:set indentkeys?` and checking if the colon was in the list (it was).

It is nearly empty, so I doubt it will be useful, but here is my `.vimrc`:

```
set nocompatible
set autoindent
set smartindent
set tabstop=8 softtabstop=0 expandtab shiftwidth=4 smarttab
inoremap <S-Tab> <C-d>
```

How can I fix VIM so it recognizes `with...as` and indents after this on a newline?

Comment: I am posting this question along with the answer. Although this problem seems rather uncommon, I hope this will help other people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is indeed in the `filetype indent on` command.

For some reason, typing it in the VIM interpreter will not do anything. Therefore, one could think that this is not the way to fix this.

However, adding the following line to the `.vimrc` effectively fixed the problem:

```
filetype indent on
```

Comment: @cumin I'm gonna check this a bit later of you will, although if you find a solution please do post it. Besides, you might consider installing the Rope plugin, it does a pretty good job.

Comment: The tab works, but I don't get an automatic indent like I expect